# Unified updates : Update private repo with updates from local files(refactored, renamed, updated) & get regular updates from original repo

Tags: github, git-push, git-rebase, git-clone, git-pull

I have just started learning to us GitHub CLI tool on Windows. Consider me a newbie
I have a use case that looks like this :

Let me summarize before i go a little deep:

> My use case is : Cloning an open source project (which updates
> regularly), i.e create a local copy of it and make modifications(including
> renaming files and folders), pushing the changes to my private repo
> but at the same time I require regular updates from the open source
> project reflected in renamed format. Do i have to rename the files &
> folder every time the project releases an update and push it to my
> private repo ?

Lets say Project A is an open source project that regularly updates its files. Project B is my private repo on GitHub. All the initial steps for linking my  Project C(local repo) to Origin(Project B) & Upstream(Project A) have been completed through the cli and config file inside .git folder.

On my computer , My local copy Project C has been obtained by using the command

> git clone "https:..../project-B.git"

Now my purpose is the following :

1.To make heavy customizations to the code itself in my local copy Project C on my computer and push those changes to my private copy: Project B. This includes but not limited to renaming the project folders and files.

2.To obtain regular updates from Project A and the same needs to be updated in the private repo Project B.

In short, My private repo project B should have my changes and the regular changes that happen from the upstream end: project A

What's the best approach to achieve this?. I'm aware of the following steps to Push my local copy into Private Repo B :

```
Step 1 : git status -->to check for the changes in local copy.
Step 2 : git add --all
Step 3 : git commit -m 'message reflecting the nature of change'
Step 4 : git push -u origin master
where origin is my Private repo B and master is the branch that contains all the files.
```

I'm also aware of pulling in the upstream files by using :

```
git pull upstream master --> to pull in the latest changes from project A onto project B.
```

My Question is therefore :

1.When exactly should I Use git pull or git rebase with find renames : Before or after I push the committed changes. My limited understanding is git rebase is to find renamed files in origin(in my use case) and make the changes ?

Or

2.I need an entirely different approach?

Or

3.An approach to the above with minor shifts?

EDIT:

I have successfully pushed my local changes (project C-> project B(private repo on on git) using the command git push -u origin master.

Only, I need to know how can I pull changes from repo Project A(open source which regularly updates) and update my current local copy which is already renamed(folder, files everything else) & other new lines of code that is added. Eventually I need to push those updated changes from Project C(local copy)--->Project B(private repo) and have my private repo UpToDate with latest commits.

EDIT : Taking a public repo docker-jitsi-meet as a repo i need regular updates from and also modified and renamed in my private repo.
I have done the following :

1.I Bare cloned the public jitsi-meet repo to my local machine.

2.git clone --bare github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet.git.

3.cd into my local copy and git push github.com/user/project.git (private repo).

4 Deleted the bare copy and cloned the repo now git clone github.com/user/project.git

5.Add the public upstream repo as a remote: git remote add upstream github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet.git.

6 git fetch --all shows me lots of changes from upstream which i need to pull in.

7. I use

> git merge upstream/master
> and the following trace is displayed :

```
$ git merge upstream/master
Auto-merging CHANGELOG.md
Auto-merging docker-compose.yml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in docker-compose.yml
Auto-merging focus/rootfs/defaults/jicofo.conf
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in focus/rootfs/defaults/jicofo.conf
CONFLICT (modify/delete): jibri/Dockerfile deleted in HEAD and modified in upstream/master.  Version upstream/master of jibri/Dockerfile left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): prosody/rootfs/etc/cont-init.d/10-config deleted in HEAD and modified in upstream/master.  Version upstream/master of prosody/rootfs/etc/cont-init.d/10-config left in tree.
Auto-merging web/rootfs/defaults/system-config.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in web/rootfs/defaults/system-config.js
Auto-merging xmpp/rootfs/defaults/conf.d/jitsi-meet.cfg.lua
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in xmpp/rootfs/defaults/conf.d/jitsi-meet.cfg.lua
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

8. I did

> git $ git merge upstream/master -X --strategy-option="find-renames=20"

and get the following :

```
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Comment: `-X` already is synonymous to `--strategy-option`, you are using the same option twice. 2) You have to first abort your in-progress merge first, before you attempt a second merge. (Again, regular Git operations. If you have questions in addition to the original one, please [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is usually to add two remotes in your local clone and then continuously merge changes from the secondary remote. A remote is like a *bookmark* for another repository; when you clone, the `origin` remote is created automatically for you, which points to the source from which you cloned.

The following commands only need to be taken once:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/project.git localclone
cd localclone
git remote add upstream https://github.com/upstream/project.git
```

Then later to "sync" your fork:

```
git fetch --all
git merge upstream/master
git push origin HEAD
```

This will merge all changes that have happened in the "main" branch of the "upstream" remote/repository since you last fetched+merged.

Note that if commits in upstream change the same lines as you did in your fork, there will be merge conflicts which you need to resolve.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the detailed answer. Could you help me more  since im a newbie:  as an example the open source repo is this https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet which I intend to modify  with renames and keep the private trpo updated always. Could you update the answer  in above  context just as an example of above repo ?

Comment: @Earthling "upstream/project.git" will be "jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet.git". "user/project.git" will be your username followed "/docker-jitsi-meet.git". Nothing else changes.

Comment: git merge upstream/main doesn't work : merge: upstream - not something we can merge. Also tried git merge upstream master:didnt work. Btw, my local clone where I'm executing the above is the renamed one. Hope I'm correct? I cloned jitsi and cloned it into my local copy, made the changes and pushed it to my private empty repo i created. Now  my understanding is to pull in my local copy the updated jitsi commits(jitsi upstream added !) and merge it with my locally renamed ones. and then push the final changes to my private repo(origin) with final renamed changes.

Comment: Based on my understanding, wouldn't pulling from upstream and then merging and/or rebase overwrite the renamed files with the original ones which defeats the purpose of renaming ? Kindly correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Earthling regarding question 1: did you add the remote and execute `git fetch --all`? What do you mean with "I cloned it into my local copy"? You cannot clone a repo into another repo, you should add a new remote instead.

Comment: @Earthling regarding question 2: no, `merge` _merges_ changes. It will not overwrite, it will apply the new changes to your moved files (which Git should be able to detect as "moved").

Comment: I cloned into my local copy means : 1.I Bare cloned the public jitsi-meet repo to my local machine. 2.git clone --bare  https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet.git.3. cd into my local copy and git push https://github.com/user/project.git (private repo). 4 Deleted the bare copy and cloned the repo now git clone https://github.com/user/project.git 5.Add the public upstream repo  as a remote: 
 git remote add upstream https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet.git. 6 git fetch --all shows me lots of changes from upstream. After that the merge throws an error.

Comment: I hope I've understood you correctly.

Comment: Now i have a local copy of jitsi which i have renamed and pushed to the private repo using git origin push master. Only the step of pulling in changes remains from jitsi end. I found your steps similar to the steps outlined here : https://alexclaydon.dev/post/2020-10-05-jitsi-meet-deployment

Comment: @Earthling I don't know what the bare repo does in your steps? 1. Clone your repo 2. add remote 3. fetch + merge (as written in my answer already) If there are (textual) conflicts, you have to resolve those (written in my answer too). "Throws an error" what error? Extend your answer by editing to include additional details.

Comment: Hi. When you said the clone your repo , did you mean the ones i have already renamed and pushed to my private repo right ? because that's what needs to be updated. That's exactly what ive done

Comment: If you already have a clone of your fork, you can obviously skip the very first command from my answer. The important bits are to add a secondary remote to your local clone, then use this remote to fetch commits from "upstream". Everything else is regular Git command: you merge branches and push branches (and Git doesn't really care about those, it's all about commits).

Comment: Hi. Updated the question with the error I'm facing.

Comment: @Earthling you have to use the correct branch name, the jitsi repo uses `master` (not `main`). I will update my answer. (many projects now use `main` as their default branch name; in the past it was `master` exclusively). But this is regular Git operations: you can only merge branches that actually exist.

Comment: Hi.  Updated the question with the merge conflicts i'm getting after doing git merge upstream/master.

Comment: @Earthling yes, you have to resolve those. Perhaps you can avoid some of them by playing around with different values for `-X find-renames=…`

Comment: --strategy-option="find-renames=20" ? Need to use rebase too ?

Comment: @Earthling no, rebase usually won't change anything. You can try, but I'd be surprised if it handled it better.

Comment: Well this procedure is creating additional original folders and the renamed ones are also existing.

Comment: This worked like you said with comparing incoming merges with current ones inside each file. However, Filenames itself which i had renamed : like 'jitsi-meet.lua' which I changed to 'my-filename.lua' had to be compared side by side which is a pain since the merge made both the files appear in the same folder. I dont think there is any other way to handle than manually comparing ?

Comment: @Earthling If a move cannot be detected (even after lowering the rename threshold) , or if there are textual conflicts, you have to resolve them manually. `rebase` instead of `merge` is worth a try, but I doubt it will change anything.