# Batch Script renaming of folder names, filenames & the contents of multiple files in windows 11

Tags: batch-file, rename, windows-11

I'm looking for a tool, (script preferably), which can rename directory contents, (child directories and files).

Before:

```
SourceDirectory
|
+---Folder A
|      filea.js
|      filey.js
```

After:

```
SourceDirectory
|
+----Folder B
|       filex.js
|       fileb.js
```

Inside `filea.js` & `fileb.js` respectively, several lines of code need to be renamed with case-sensitivity taken into consideration. This is exactly similar to how Notepad++ would execute operations to the contents of a file with 'match-case option'`.

In a nutshell:

1. Renaming of folders.
2. Renaming of filenames inside folders.
3. Renaming of the contents of each filename.

I'm looking for a single script to execute, since this process needs to be repeated every once in a while.

My problem comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75094702), which I posted a while back, and for which I received no answers.

My original question is pulling in regular updates from an open source git repo , renaming it for my own purpose, modifying the code, and pushing the same to my private repo.

Comment: Your linked question not only received an answer, but you accepted it too!

Comment: Sorry for that. I shouldn't have done that without trying out if it works. I have retracted.